# Toggling click handlers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, handler

I have an HTML button to which I attach an event, using jQuery's `bind()`, like so:

```
$('#mybutton').bind('click', myFirstHandlerFunction);
```

In `myFirstHandlerFunction`, I'd like this handler to replace itself with a new handler, `mySecondHandlerFunction`, like this:

```
function myFirstHandlerFunction(e) {
    $(this).unbind('click', myFirstHandlerFunction).bind('click', mySecondHandlerFunction);
}
```

In the second click handler, `mySecondHandlerFunction`, I'd like to toggle the button back to its original state: unbind the `mySecondHandlerFunction` handler and reattach the original handler, `myFirstHandlerFunction`, like so:

```
function mySecondHandlerFunction(e) {
    $(this).unbind('click', mySecondHandlerFunction).bind('click', myFirstHandlerFunction);
}
```

This works great, except for one small detail: because the click event has not yet propagated through each of the button's click handlers, the click event is passed on to the button's next click handler, which happens to be the handler that was just bound in the previous handler.  The end result is `mySecondHandlerFunction` being executed immediately after `myFirstHandlerFunction` is executed.

This problem can be easily solved by calling `e.stopPropagation()` in each handler, but this has the negative side-effect of cancelling any other click handlers that may have been attached independently.

Is there a way to safely and and consistently toggle between two click handlers, without having to stop the propagation of the click event?

Comment: Why don't you use a flag to check which handler to invoke and always attach a master handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Update:** Since this form of `toggle()` was removed in jQuery 1.9, the solution below does not work anymore. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459153/alternative-to-jquerys-toggle-method-that-supports-eventdata) for
>   alternatives.

It looks like [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) would solve your problem:

```
$("#mybutton").toggle(myFirstHandlerFunction, mySecondHandlerFunction);
```

The code above will register `myFirstHandlerFunction` and `mySecondHandlerFunction` to be called on alternate clicks.

Comment: The .toggle(eventHandlers) was depreciated in jQuery 1.8, and removed in 1.9+. This is no longer a viable option. -[Source](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Answer (score 6):

Just use a boolean to toggle the functionality of the handler, there's no need to juggle which handler is listening:

```
$('#mybutton').bind('click', myHandlerFunction);
var first = true;

function myHandlerFunction(e) {
    if(first){
        // Code from the first handler here;
    }else{
        // Code from the second handler here;
    }
    first = !first; // Invert `first`
}
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, `.toggle` is probably better, but +1 for showing logic on how to do this without the use of `.toggle`

Comment: As commented above, `toggle` is deprecated in 1.9 and removed in 1.10. Don't use it.

Comment: I like this one better using data attribute instead of global : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2459225/781695

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a hack, but it *is* short and sweet for your rough work:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  (this.firstClk = !this.firstClk) ? firstHandler(): secondHandler();
});
```

It's a hack because it's putting a new property directly onto `this` which is the click-target HTML DOM element, and that's maybe not best practice. However, it thus avoids creates any new globals, and it can be used unchanged on different buttons simultaneously.

Note that the first part of the ternary operation uses `=` and not `==` or `===`, i.e. it's an assignment, not a comparison. Note also that the first time the button is clicked, `this.firstClk` is undefined but is immediately negated, making the first part of the ternary operation evaluate to `true` the first time.

Here's a working version:

```js
$('#a > button').click(function() {(this.firstClk = !this.firstClk) ? a1(): a2();});
$('#b > button').click(function() {(this.firstClk = !this.firstClk) ? b1(): b2();});

function a1() {$('#a > p').text('one');}
function a2() {$('#a > p').text('two');}

function b1() {$('#b > p').text('ONE');}
function b2() {$('#b > p').text('TWO');}
```

```css
div {display: inline-block;width: 10em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"><p>not yet clicked</p><button>click</button></div>
<div id="b"><p>NOT YET CLICKED</p><button>CLICK</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this today, and realized there was still not a way to do this without a global variable listed. I came up with the following to add locations to an ESRI basemap, but it would work generally too:

```
function addLocationClickHandler() {
    var addLocationClick = overviewMap.on('click', function (event) {
        addLocationClick.remove();
    })
    $('#locationAddButton').one('click', function (cancelEvent) {
        addLocationClick.remove();
        $('#locationAddButton').on('click', addLocationClickHandler)
    });
}

$('#locationAddButton').on('click', addLocationClickHandler)
```

This should allow you to put something else in the section where you overwrite the click handler and not necessitate a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This would help add `data-click-state` attribute on your button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
            $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
            myFirstHandlerFunction();
        } else {
            $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
            mySecondHandlerFunction();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this approach!

Answer (score -2):

Like this:

```
$(this).bind('click', myMasterHandler);

handler = 0;

function myMasterHandler(e) {
    if(handler == 0) {
        myFirstHandler(e);
        handler = 1;
    } else {
        mySecondHandler(e);
        handler = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The downvote is not mine, but it may be related to `handler` being global instead of local, or to the use of `0` and `1` instead of a boolean, or to the fact that the current value of `this` is not properly propagated to the handlers.