# .toggle() replacement for jQuery 1.8+

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to jQuery’s .toggle() method that supports eventData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459153/alternative-to-jquerys-toggle-method-that-supports-eventdata)

I was just wondering if there was an alternative for the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function used to bind two event handlers to alernate clicks (not the one to toggle visibility).

It has been deprecated in jQuery 1.8, and removed in version 1.9. I just wanted to know if there's another function capable of doing that now and that I wouldn't be aware of in jQuery 1.8+. I don't want an example of how to make it myself, I just want to know if another function that is able to do the same thing is available in jQuery.

Comment: There is no single function; that behavior was removed.  Instead, just use `.click` and check something to determine which toggle stat it's in.  Not what you want, but that's the answer.

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786

Comment: Thanks, that's all I wanted to know.