# How to fix toggle() using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Latest version of JQuery does not support toggle method any more. So I found one solution how to fix it, I can add jquery-migrate.js - this library contains all old methods which is not supported now.

But I think it's dirty solution, to add library only for fixing one method.
Does anyone have an idea - how to return this method whith js?

Comment: [This `.toggle` method?](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) I’m pretty sure it’s still supported…

Comment: @Mongo - It's the toggle event that was deprecated. The animation method still exists.

Comment: @j08691 I'm not sure if that's a proper duplicate

Comment: @RUJordan - I was going to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465173/toggle-replacement-for-jquery-1-8 but the other contains a suitable code replacement. Here's another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287007/replacement-for-toggle-in-jquery-1-9

Comment: Or mine: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4911577/218196 ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling tnx!!! perfect solution, I saw your question before, but could not find it.