# .toggle() only hiding it's target element, not toggling states on alternate clicks

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a button which toggles the visibility of the two elements on every other click...this working fine up to a few days ago but now on page load it hides the button. I found that .toggle also works to show/hide elements but how do you use it to toggle between functions on alternate clicks?

JS:

```
$("#button").toggle(
     function(){
          $('#stuff1').hide("slow");
          $('#stuff2').show("slow");
     },
     function(){ 
          $('#stuff1').show("slow");
          $('#stuff2').hide("slow"); 
     }
);
```

HTML:

```
<img id="button" src="button.jpg"/>
<p id="stuff1">stuff</p> 
<p id="stuff2">stuff</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it stopped working for you is because this `toggle` overload was deprecated in 1.8 but you didn't notice, and was removed in 1.9 and only now you noticed:

```
.toggle( handler(eventObject), handler(eventObject) [, handler(eventObject) ] )
```

**version deprecated: 1.8, removed: 1.9**

Use use `toggle` function:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
      $('#stuff1').toggle("slow");
      $('#stuff2').toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, I thought about it, but jQuery has a special regex for matching single id selector which is extremely fast, if you add something to it, it can't be used. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: I almost forgot about that detail. Caching the jQuery object obtained from the selector `$('#stuff1, #stuff2')` into a variable would work though. But that's out of the scope of the question, never mind that. `=]`

Comment: Though, now I wonder if creating 2 jQuery objects with 2 `document.getElementById` pays off a single object utilizing QSA.. Will do benchmarks some other time. The microseconds.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, this is a micro-optimization, I see no point checking it out except if it's motivated y curiosity.

Comment: Just curiosity actually. I'd personally go with the shorter code to save some bytes from the JS file. And I know that the pure ID selector is much faster when compared to QSA so e.g. `$('#foo')` is recommended over `$('div#foo')`, but just to compare 2 objects generated through ID selectors vs 1 QSA: http://jsperf.com/2-id-selectors-vs-1-qsa - you are right, the pure ID selectors outweigh the overhead of extra function calls.

Comment: Ah- that makes sense. Is there a way to effect multiple objects then? The way .toggle used to work? Say if I wanted to change the background image of the button via  .css and use .hide/.show on #stuff1/#stuff2? I'm new here so let me know if I should just ask a different question

Comment: @user1922019, I didn't understand the question.

Comment: I actually found a method here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459153/alternative-to-jquerys-toggle-method-that-supports-eventdata
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Jquery**

```
$("#button").click(
     function(){         
          $('#stuff1').toggle("slow");
          $('#stuff2').toggle("slow");
     }

);
```

**CSS**

```
#stuff1
{
    display:none;
}
```