# switch img src back again after jquery click

Tags: jquery, html

i have managed to switch my crosshair to a minus using jquery but cannot write the query to reset on re-click. I'm trying and trying. The second/minus img is picked from the img directory.

my HTML-

```
<div id="button-1"><img id="crosshair" src="img/plus.jpg" alt="plus"></div>
```

Jquery (initial)-

```
$('#crosshair').on({
'click': function(){
    $('#crosshair').attr('src','img/minus.jpg');
}
});
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: check here:
[Registering jQuery click, first and second click][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914372/registering-jquery-click-first-and-second-click

Answer (score 0):

Add a check condition.

```
$('#crosshair').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.attr('src', $this.attr('stc') === 'img/minus.jpg' ? 'img/plus.jpg' : 'img/minus.jpg');
});
```

Comment: I believe you meant `.attr('src')`.