# Running the reverse of .animate on a second click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

By following the example at Registering jQuery click, first and second click. I was able to solve my issue by basically adding back the depreciated .toggle function.

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
if (clicks) {//on odd clicks this will run
    $( "#wrapper" ).animate({
        paddingLeft: "170px"
        }, 500 );
    $( ".side-nav" ).animate({
        width: "170px",
        fontSize: "14px",

        }, 500 );
}
else{//on even clicks this will run
    $( "#wrapper" ).animate({
        paddingLeft: "38px"
        }, 500 );
    $( ".side-nav" ).animate({
        width: "45px",
        fontSize: "18px",
        left: "215px",
        paddingLeft:"2px"
        }, 500 );

}
$(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

old code

```
    $( "#go" ).click(function() {
    $( "#wrapper" ).animate({
        paddingLeft: "38px"
        }, 500 );
    $( ".side-nav" ).animate({
        width: "45px",
        fontSize: "18px",
        left: "215px",
        paddingLeft:"2px"
        }, 500 );
    });
```

I need the code above to run in reverse on a second click on #go. I've been running in circles with .toggle, jQuery UI options and stackoverflow posts but I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Save the current state and animate to the new value. When pressed again animate to the saved value and so on...

Comment: I don't know how to save a state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the animation and the reverse in two functions, and use a class to check if you have to start an animation or the other, like this:

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/puviwo/3/edit)

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('isAnimated')) {
   $(this).addClass('isAnimated');
   anim1();
  } else {
   $(this).remove('isAnimated');
   anim2();
  }
});


function anim1 (){
....
}

function anim2 (){
....
}
```

Comment: This seems a far more elegant solution than my own

Comment: Yes, it follows the JS (and i guess all programming language in general) best practice that is to separate the code/function in small chunk, to better debug and handle. :-)

Comment: And, as suggets, always, ALWAYS, avoid the use of jQuery toggle method.

Answer (score 0):

By following the example at [Registering jQuery click, first and second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914372/registering-jquery-click-first-and-second-click). I was able to solve my issue by basically adding back the depreciated .toggle function.

```
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {//on odd clicks this will run
        $( "#wrapper" ).animate({
            paddingLeft: "170px"
            }, 500 );
        $( ".side-nav" ).animate({
            width: "170px",
            fontSize: "14px",

            }, 500 );
    }
    else{//on even clicks this will run
        $( "#wrapper" ).animate({
            paddingLeft: "38px"
            }, 500 );
        $( ".side-nav" ).animate({
            width: "45px",
            fontSize: "18px",
            left: "215px",
            paddingLeft:"2px"
            }, 500 );

    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
    });
```