# Targeting a div with the right selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML:

```
<tr class="main">
    <td class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="dropdown-image"></div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="from">from</td>
    <td class="subject">subject</td>
    <td class="received">received</td>
    <td class="status">Quarantined</td>
    <td class="action">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="dropdown-menu"></div>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to target the `.dropdown-menu` to change it's background image once the `.dropdown-image` has been clicked.

My JavaScript:

```
$(function) {
    $('.dropdown-image').click(function() {
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
        var td = $(this).parent().parent();
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

        if (clicks) {
            td.closest('.action').child().child().css("background-image", "url(images/new-arrow.png)");
        } else {
            td.closest('.action').child().child().css("background-image", "url(images/new-arrow-blue.png)");
        }
        $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I target the `.dropdown-menu` correctly?

Comment: what about syntax error there : `$(this).data("clicks, !clicks);` ?

Comment: Those `<a>`s need some sort of text content for screen reader accessibility. Something like `aria-label="toggle menu"` is one way to fix the issue.

Comment: The JavaScript click handler should be on the `<a>`, not on the `<div>` (for keyboard accessibility). Also consider replacing the `<a>`s with `<button>`s and dropping the `href` attr (because they're not really links).

Comment: @danielnixon what on earth is aria-lebelling? I think i went with the div only because when i wrote my css and put the class on the a link the css attributes wouldnt work but will look at changing this thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914372/registering-jquery-click-first-and-second-click @AliMasudianPour this is just my bad retyping! i have not copy and pasted, it is all fine on my real code!

Comment: @danielnixon is this ie9 compatible?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=wai-aria

Comment: @danielnixon every time i move the class to the a link, the a shows up as 0px x 0px no matter what i set it as, im doing something wrong do you know what that is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use the `.closest()` method to find the sibling `'.action'` element, but that's not what `.closest()` does. As explained in [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/closest), it looks for a matching ancestor element. So you can get the tr element that the clicked div belongs to like this:

```
var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
```

And then you can find the dropdown-menu div that belongs in that tr using [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - which is like the opposite of `.closest()` in that it looks for a descendant:

```
tr.find(".dropdown-menu")
```

In other words, to find the related `.dropdown-menu`, navigate up to the tr with `.closest()` and then back down to the related div with `.find()`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown-image').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            clicks = $this.data('clicks'),
            $relatedDiv = $this.closest("tr").find(".dropdown-menu");

        if (clicks) {
            $relatedDiv.css("background-image", "url(images/new-arrow.png)");
        } else {
            $relatedDiv.css("background-image", "url(images/new-arrow-blue.png)");
        }
        $this.data("clicks", !clicks);
    });
});
```

Note that I only call `$(this)` *once,* putting the result in a variable. This is more efficient.

Also, as has been pointed out in comments, you have two syntax errors:

- the first line should be `$(function() {` (you have incorrect parentheses)
- the third-last line is missing a `"` before the comma.

Comment: And there has a error in the first line. Should be `$(function() {` instead of `$(function){`. And another error in the `$this.data("clicks, !clicks);`, see that this line has no double quotes after clicks.

Comment: That was just bad retyping on my part @IagoMelanias it is correct in my real code i just rewrote it here to simplify it!

Comment: Ok, i just cited because someone can reuse this code for something else.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
 $(function () {
  $('.dropdown-image').click(function () {
    var $relatedDiv = $(this).parents('tr.main').find('.dropdown-menu');
    $relatedDiv.toggleClass('bg-image-new-arrow-blue');
    $relatedDiv.toggleClass('bg-image-new-arrow');
  });
});
```

css

```
 .bg-image-new-arrow{
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url(images/new-arrow.png) no-repeat;
  }
  .bg-image-new-arrow-blue{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 23px;
    background: url(images/new-arrow-blue.png) no-repeat;
  }
```

html

```
<table>
  <tr class="main">
    <td class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="dropdown-image">asasdasdd</div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="from">from</td>
    <td class="subject">subject</td>
    <td class="received">received</td>
    <td class="status">Quarantined</td>
    <td class="action">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="dropdown-menu bg-image-new-arrow-blue">DropDown menu</div>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The related is code-pen is in [this link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYbQPM)