# jQuery: .toggle code atlernative not working on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I'm making a website element containing a text box that would expand when a correct span is clicked. The span would toggle between having the mask of the box have parameters x, and parameters y (being default).
In the [Registering jQuery click, first and second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914372/registering-jquery-click-first-and-second-click) answer I found the right code. After tweaking the names it looked like this:

```
$('#more').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
      $('.text').css('clip', 'rect(0px,375px,220px,0px);');
      $(this).css('top', '815px;');
  } else {
    $('.text').css('clip', 'rect(0px,375px,800px,0px)');
      $(this).css('top', '235px;');
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Unfortunately the code works only on the first click, and only for the .text element (the more span does not move at all).

What could be wrong with this code, and how can it be fixed?
Would be glad for any help.

Also. For additional information:
-html of the portion

```
<div class="txtbox">
    <div class="text">       
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p> 
    </div> 
</div>
<span class="extbutton" id="more">more info:</span>
```

And the styles of inner elements:

```
.text{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    width: 375px;
    height: 700px;
    color: white;
    left: 315px;
    top: 18px;
    background-color:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    clip: rect(0px,375px,220px,0px); 
    z-index:0;

}

.text, #more{
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.extbutton{
    color: white;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}


#more{
    position:absolute;
    width:375px;
    left:315px;
    top:235px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#more').click(function(){
  
$('#textToHide').toggleClass('hideText');
});
```

```css
.text{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position:realtive;
    width: 375px;
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
    left: 315px;
    top: 18px;
    background-color:  gray;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.hideText{
   
   height:700px;
}

.text, #more{
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.extbutton{
    color: white;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
}


#more{
    position:realtive;
    display:block;
    width:375px;
    
    
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div   class="txtbox">
    <div  id="textToHide" class="text ">       
        <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p> 
    </div> 
</div>
<span class="extbutton " id="more">more info:</span>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you...but...how? I mean I can't understand this code. Could you provide quick explanation?

Comment: yep ,
$('#more').click(function(){
  
$('#textToHide').toggleClass('hideText');
});
this mean once i click the more span , what will happen is that in texttohide ID i will remove the class hideText and when i click again it will add the class.
you can see that in this class i have the height change.