# Java Script change AddClass after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

with this code read "pnotify-no-title" and after click show Check Text with bg-primary Class; now i need after one click show Check text with bg-primary and after next click show check2 text with bg-primary2 class and again after next click show check text with bg-primary class

```
  $('#pnotify-no-title').on('click', function () {
    new PNotify({
        text: 'Check',
        addclass: 'bg-primary'

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to record alternate clicks. One easy way is to add a class to the object to record which click it is

```
  $('#pnotify-no-title').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    new PNotify({
        text: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'Check2' : 'Check',
        addclass: $this.hasClass('odd-click') ? 'bg-primary2' : 'bg-primary'

    });

    $this.toggleClass('odd-click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

```
$('#pnotify-no-title').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    new PNotify({
        text: 'Check',
        addclass: 'bg-primary'

    });
  } else {
    new PNotify({
        text: 'Check',
        addclass: 'bg-primary2'

    });
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

**[Main Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914372/registering-jquery-click-first-and-second-click)**

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/qcybuxek/)**

Comment: this is exactly what you wanted, odd and even click, what you have expect? @SaeEdx , anyway, it doesn't matter anymore, you got you answer.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery toggleClass function..
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp