# failing on trying to change specific div width that repeat it self on php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

On my PHP project I have some comment box div that repeat it self, how ever every time I want some one who is clicking on it (the div itself), to change the width of the div to 100%, the problem comes here, whenever I try making something like this, it is changing all divs width and not individually to the specific box it self , is there any solution that comes up in your head?

Comment: If you want help, we need to see some code. As it is, you're being too vague.

Answer (score 2):

Just set an `ID` to your `div` (if you want just to modify only one item in the whole webpage) and make reference to it from `JQuery` (as you have tagged it).

If you want to modify all the `divs` in which you click (but only the `div` in which you click will be changed each time) then you can refer to the `class` associated to each div.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".div").click(function() {
      $(this).css("width", "100%");
    });
});
```

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="div"></div>
<div id="id2" class="div"></div>
```

**EDIT:** If you want that they will be back to their initial position just do an `if` statement in your `Javascript`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".div").click(function() {
    if($(this).css("width") == "100px")
      $(this).css("width", "100%");
    else
      $(this).css("width", "100px");
  }); 
});
```

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="div"></div>
<div id="id2" class="div"></div>
```

Comment: `$('.div').click(...)` would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @Steve Totally agree. I misunderstood the question and thought that he want just one in all the document. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You need to update your answer text to reflect this though (`"Just set an ID..."`)

Comment: @Steve Yes, I was editing it too :)

Comment: @Error404 what if I want second click will get it back to normal?

Comment: @s.f.b.h Look at my edit answer :)

Comment: @Error404 tried using your new function but it seems to work poorly, my div size is flexible so I can't define a size for it, if you have any other ideas it could be nice, thank you.

Comment: @s.f.b.h try with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914372/registering-jquery-click-first-and-second-click#answer-14914382)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an unique identifier like `id` or `class`(apparently) or use `event` object to find out which DOM element is clicked

Using class

```
 //probable html
<div class = "abc"></div>
 <div class = "abc"></div>
 <div class = "abc"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.abc').click(function(){
     $(this). addClass('a class which will set to 100%') // or use .css
    })
```

**Using Event object**

```
 $('div').on('click',function(event){
   var _target = event.target;
    $(_target).addClass('class which will make it 100%')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the clicked div and define width of 100% for that class:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="comment">Comment 1</div>
<div class="comment">Comment 2</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.comment').on('click', function() {
    $('.activeComment').removeClass('activeComment');
    $(this).addClass('activeComment');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.comment {width: 50%;}
.comment.activeComment {width: 100%;}
```

**[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12rbxeoc/)**