# jQuery .toggle event deprecated, What to use?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.8

Since the jQuery .toggle event method is deprecated.
What are we suppose to use to simulate this event (alternate clicks)?

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459153/alternative-to-jquerys-toggle-method-that-supports-eventdata

Comment: @jahroy I don't want an animation method...

Comment: I did read the documentation and the toggle() animation method toggles the visibility of an element, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14301935/778118) will help. (sorry I mis-read your question at first)

Comment: I want a toggle event. Mr Jay Lane gave me a good answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Okay, I will look at that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this outside of document.ready

```
$.fn.clicktoggle = function(a, b) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var clicked = false;
        $(this).click(function() {
            if (clicked) {
                clicked = false;
                return b.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            clicked = true;
            return a.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    });
};
```

then use the following to replicate the .toggle functionality:

```
$("#mydiv").clicktoggle(functionA,functionB);
```

Found on the [JQuery Forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is this? Is it a function you wrote? Why $.fn.clicktoggle and how do you call this function? Thank you for your anwser!

Comment: The above code extends the jQuery object by adding a new method.  You would add that code to your "_on ready_" handler.  Then you can invoke `clicktoggle()` as if it was a jQuery method.  You can read about adding a jQuery method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12093192/778118).

Comment: no problem, if it worked for you if you can add it as solved that would be great

Comment: Yes, I have to wait 4 minutes :).

Answer (score -1):

```
var i = 0;    
$('button').click(function() { 
    if (i == 0){        
        $('div').css({background: 'red'}) 
        i++; 
    } else { 
        $('div').css({background: 'yellow'}) 
        i = 0; 
    }
});
```