# Issue on Toggling Two Functions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let ma know how I can call/toggle two functions from outside of the toggle()

```js
function printConsole() {
  console.log("This is From Function A");
}

function printAlert() {
  alert("This is From Function B");
}

$("#toggler").toggle(
  printConsole(); printAlert();
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggler">Toggle Fnctions</button>
```

Comment: 1. your code is not valid; 2. you cannot _toggle_ functions; 3. you want to use a [click handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: What do you mean by _toggling_ two functions?

Comment: Well then do it : )) Keep track of the number of clicks in a variable, and call a function accordingly.

Comment: just not sure why this question down voted!

Comment: This `toggle` functionality has been deprecated since version 1.8. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246 for a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing functions in an array , utilizing `.click()` , `Array.prototype.reverse()`

```js
function printConsole() {
  console.log("This is From Function A");
}

function printAlert() {
  alert("This is From Function B");
}

var fns = [printConsole, printAlert];

$("#toggler").click(function() {
  fns[0]();
  fns.reverse();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggler">Toggle Fnctions</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guest271314!

Answer (score 0):

**Depreciated in jquery 1.8**

use comma, try this code:

```
$("#toggler").toggle(
  function() {
  console.log("This is From Function A");
},function() {
  alert("This is From Function B");
}
);
```

reference: https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

**Update**

Use this Instead:

```
var clicks = true;
$('a').click(function() {
  if (clicks) {
    alert('Function A');
    clicks = false;
  } else {
    alert('Function B');
    clicks = true;
  }
});
```

reference: [Alternative to jQuery's .toggle() method that supports eventData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459153/alternative-to-jquerys-toggle-method-that-supports-eventdata)

Comment: This was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Comment: Thanks Shaminder S Aujla, so there isnt a way to call the functions inside the toggle()?